# Daylight Saving Time handing in PHP

Tags: php

I am running this on an AWS hosted Ubuntu 22.04 instance.

```
PHP version: PHP 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.11 (cli) (built: Feb 22 2023 22:56:18) (NTS)

<?php
$date = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('PST'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

I'm getting

```
2023-03-24 00:42:17
```

When I know, it's

```
 2023-03-24 01:42:17
```

I thought PHP handles DST conversion automatically.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: For what it's worth, [Pacific Standard Time (PST)](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/pst) is not currently active anywhere. I don't know when you executed the script (you don't provide a UTC time as reference) but PHP seems to return the correct time nonetheless: https://3v4l.org/1GOVL#v8.2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Western US timezone is either PST (Pacific Standard Time) or PDT (Pacific Daylight Time). If you explicitly specify PST, then you explicitly get PST. That's why you should never use these abbreviations, but one of the timezones listed in https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php, like `America/Los_Angeles`, which will switch between PST and PDT correctly.